# Does SQLAlchemyAutoSchema pick up hybrid properties?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have a model with a few hybrid properties and I'm using `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` to autogenerate a `marshmallow` schema based on my model. However, I don't think it's picking up the hybrid properties in the model.

Is there any way for `SQLAlchemyAutoSchema` to pick up the hybrid properties and turn them into `marshmallow` fields for deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

Per their documentation, it does not - https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/blob/7b354a8d5c679a559198710417b958bf2058d11d/docs/index.rst